# Where is the PDE solution defined?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Given $\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial t} + \cos(t)\dfrac {\partial u}{\partial x}=0,\ t>0$ with $u(x,0)=f(x)\  0<x<1$, I need to determine where this solution is defined.

I have found using the characteristic curve that $u(x,t)=F(x-\sin(t))$ is the solution satisfying $u(x,0)=f(x)$, but given $0<x<1$ then surely $\ -1 < x-\sin(t)<2$, thus the solution  is defined on $(-1,2)$.

Is this correct?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. The solution will be defined precisely where $F(x-\sin(t))$ is defined. Given the initial condition, you have $F(x)=f(x)$, and so the solution is $u(x,t)=F(x-\sin(t))$. But $f(x)$ is only defined on $(0,1)$, so you have that

$$
0<x-\sin(t)<1
$$
Or, to put it slightly differently,
$$
\sin(t)<x<1+\sin(t)
$$
So, for instance, when $t=\pi/2$, you have $1<x<2$, while for $t=3\pi/2$, you have $-1<x<0$. At time $t=\pi/2$, the solution isn't defined for $x<1$.